# How to add font awesome icon in Custom HTML Helper in ASP.Net MVC 5 application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I want to use font awesome icons in my custom HTML Helper but I am not able to do so.

Below is my attempt:

HTML HELPER

```
   public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var currentArea = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];

        var builder = new TagBuilder("li")
        {
            InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString()
        };
        if (String.Equals(controllerName, currentController, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && String.Equals(actionName, currentAction, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            builder.AddCssClass("active");
        //builder.AddCssClass("btn");

        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Custom Action Link

```
     @Html.MenuLink("Resume Center", "Index", "Resume", null, new { @class = "btn btn-block"})
```

I modified above link but it does not work as expected. Non working example below.

```
 @Html.MenuLink("<i class='fa fa - file'></i> Resume Center", "Index", "Resume", null, new { @class = "btn btn-block"})
```

Original HTML the gets rendered by Custom Helper:

```
<li class="active">
    <a class="btn btn-block" href="/Resume">Resume Center</a>
</li>
```

I want something like

```
<li class="active">
    <a class="btn btn-block" href="/Resume">
        <i class="fa fa-file"></i>Resume Center
    </a>
</li>
```

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Did you want the icon and the text?

Comment: I want <Icon> followed by "Resume Center". I am using the generic HTML Helper you suggested to use once. I want to use something like `var lIconBuilder = new TagBuilder("i");
            lIconBuilder.MergeAttribute("class", "fa fa-file");`

Comment: But I am not sure how to Merge it in my original HTML Helper `li` tag

Comment: The `InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(...)` code only generates an `<a>` element. Give me 15 min and I'll add an answer with the code you need to modify

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Ok Sir, till then I will try to add bits and pieces and will do some research/experimentation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I added a working solution based out of @@Mindless's answer. But like you suggested I do not want add more noise to my code and want to utilize the power of helpers. If I follow @@Mindless solution then I won't be able to pass attribute and all gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionLink()` only generates an `<a>` tag. You will need to replace `InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(...)` with your own code to manually build the html.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var currentArea = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
        // Build the icon and display text elements
        StringBuilder innerHtml = new StringBuilder();
        TagBuilder icon = new TagBuilder("i");
        icon.AddCssClass("fa fa-file");
        innerHtml.Append(icon.ToString());
        TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
        span.InnerHtml = linkText;
        innerHtml.Append(span.ToString());
        // Build the link
        TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("a");
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        string url = urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
        link.MergeAttribute("href", url);
        link.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        link.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
        // Build the li element
        TagBuilder li = new TagBuilder("li");
        li.InnerHtml = link.ToString();
        if (String.Equals(controllerName, currentController, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && String.Equals(actionName, currentAction, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            li.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        // Return the html
        return new MvcHtmlString(li.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Since my all menu items will have different icons. I can pass them as an argument. I will try this code and will get back to you. @@Mindless solution looks simple to me, even though it has alot of hardcoding. That being said, I think I will have more learning if I follow your solution.

Comment: Do you mean your want to specify different class names in the `<i>` element? If so then, yes add an additional parameter(say `string iconClass` and then use `icon.AddCssClass(iconClass);`

Comment: Yes, I will do that, it will provide the flexibility that I need. :)

Comment: It also would not have worked because you could not add the html attributes to the `<a>` element :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152370/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-stephen-muecke).